# user verfication doesnt sent an email laravel

Tags: laravel, email, verification

i followed the steps of this tutorial: 
https://www.5balloons.info/user-email-verification-and-account-activation-in-laravel-5-5/

and everything works so if i register a new user it creates a new user in my database and it shows me no error

but im waitng for a half hour but i dont get a mail

does anyone know if its because i am on localhost and not on a real sever??

because i dont know what is the problem because it seems that everything works

Comment: did you setup correctly your email credentials in .env file located at the project root folder? Do you see any erros on the laravel log file by doing when registering a new user.

command to check erros: `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=2525

MAIL_USERNAME=efaea9a7b1713f
MAIL_PASSWORD=a5a09892d32fe5

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

these are my email credentials

Comment: what about your APP_ENV, APP_DEBUG variables? are they set to local and true?

Comment: does your mailtrap account you received any event at all? if possible try to check your laravel log, to make sure there is no erros. use the command in the comment above

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-sending-mail-via-mailtrap-not-working-with-no-errors this post suggest to restart your dev server. you can try if it works with you

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.5?

Comment: ahhhh i got the mail, i dont know that they sent the mail to my mailtrap so i looked in my own mailbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved in the comments